# UWP: MediaCapture audio stream interrupted/resumed states

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, mediacapture

I am working on UWP simple recording app. `MediaCapture` instance successfully initialized and I did successful attempt for capturing audio stream.

Now, there is a task to support different states of the microphone.

On the mobile platform there might be incoming calls and we monitoring such events by system notifications:
`audioSessionInterruptionStarted` and `audioSessionInterruptionEnded` (iOS example)

How similar behavior can be achieved on `UWP`? According to the documentation there is [MediaCapture.FocusChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.focuschanged) which sends `MediaCaptureFocusState` enum with different states:

- Failed
- Focused
- Lost
- Searching
- Uninitialized

Can anyone explain me in details what each of these states means and can I use it for monitoring audio stream interruption states?

Comment: Hi, when capturing audio, you can try to use `FocusChanged` to track changes in the state of the device. Have you tried it? Did something happen during use? If suspended, the `Failed` or `Lost` status may be triggered. This may be caused by the device being disconnected or due to a change in the device ’s exclusive status. You can listen to the `CaptureDeviceExclusiveControlStatusChanged` event

Comment: `CaptureDeviceExclusiveControlStatusChanged` does losing exclusive control mean that I still will receive audio buffer chunks from mic?

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad, as described in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.capturedeviceexclusivecontrolstatuschanged): *An app that does not have exclusive control of the capture device can still capture media, but it can't change the capture settings.* So when you lose your monopoly, you can still receive audio.

Comment: Yes, what's I read also. I am interested in cases when mic is captured by different application and I can not get the sound from the mic? Is it possible scenario on windows platform?

Comment: This involves the issue of device permissions. Under normal circumstances, applications can get audio through the device, but in exclusive cases, other applications cannot modify related settings.